# Prove that $a_n = 1 + \frac{1}{a_{n-1}}$ with $a_0 = 1$ converges to $\frac{1+\sqrt{5}}{2}$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

As the title says, I want to prove that $a_n = 1 + \frac{1}{a_{n-1}}$ with $a_0 = 1$ converges to $\frac{1+\sqrt{5}}{2}$. I've noticed that there's a recurrence formula $a_{n+2} = 2 - \frac{1}{a_n+1}$ and that there are two monotonic sequences in different directions $a_{2n}$ and $a_{2n+1}$. From here I need to show that they converge to the same number and that that number is $\frac{1+\sqrt{5}}{2}$ but I'm not sure how to do that.

Comment: There is a [standard way](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rational_difference_equation#First_approach) to solve it

Comment: @Marco Finding an explicit form for $a_n$ is not necessary to prove convergence to the limit

Comment: First show they are a cauchy sequence.  That is:  For any $\epsilon > 0$ then there is an $N$ so that if $n,m > M\implies |a_n - a_m|< \epsilon$.  That indicates the sequence most convert to *something*.  Then note that $\lim_{n\to \infty} a_n$ must equal $\lim_{n\to\infty}a_{n+1} = \lim_{n\to\infty}(1 + \frac 1{a_n})$.  Use the idea that if $f$ is continuous that $\lim f(n) = f(\lim n)$ to show that if $\lim_{n\to\infty} a_n = a$ then $ \lim_{n\to\infty}(1 + \frac 1{a_n})=1+\frac 1{\lim a_n}= 1+\frac 1a$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A common approach to these questions is as follows: first, find a suitable candidate for the limit under the assumption that the limit exists. Then, show that the sequence converges to this number.

The first of these steps is technically unnecessary for the question as it is presented here, but I think it may be informative in any case, so I present it at the end of my post. Once a limit is hypothesized, there are a few approaches to show that the sequence converges to the limit $L = \frac{1 + \sqrt{5}}{2}$.

#### Approach 1

Use the theory of [fixed-point iteration](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fixed-point_iteration). In particular, we see that this sequence of the form $a_n = f(a_{n-1})$, where $f: \Bbb R \to \Bbb R$ is the continuous and differentiable given by $f(x) = 1 + 1/x$. We compute $a_2 = 3/2$. We note that
$$
f'(x) = -1/x^2,
$$
and we see that $|f'(x)| < 1$ for $3/2 \leq x \leq 2$, which is a closed interval containing both $L$ and $a_2$. By the Banach fixed-point theorem, we can conclude that $a_n$ must converge to the unique fixed point in this interval, which is to say that $a_n \to L$.

#### Approach 2

Directly show that $|a_n - L|$ is strictly decreasing. To begin, we first note that $a_n > 0 \implies a_{n+1} > 0$, so that the entire sequence must be positive. Indeed, if $a_n > 0$, then $a_{n+1} = 1 + \frac 1{a_n} > 1 + 0$.

With that, we have the even stronger statement that $a_n \geq 1$ for all $n$ (and $a_n > 1$ for $n \geq 1$).

Now, making use of the fact that $L = 1 + 1/L$ (see approach 1 above or my note at the end), we note that
$$
\begin{align*}
\left|a_{n+1} - L\right| 
&= \left|1 + \frac{1}{a_n} - L\right|\\
\\ & = \left|1 + \frac 1{a_n} - \left[1 + \frac 1L\right]\right|\\
\\ & = \left|\frac 1{a_n} - \frac{1}{L}\right|\\
\\ &  = \frac{|L - a_n|}{a_n L}
\leq \frac{|L - a_n|}{L}
\end{align*}
$$
With that, we have shown that $|L - a_{n+1}| \leq \frac 1L|L - a_n|$, where we note that $1/L < 1$. It follows that $|L - a_{n}|$ converges to zero, which is to say that $a_n \to L$, which is what we wanted.

---

#### Finding a candidate for the limit

Suppose that $\lim_{n \to \infty} a_n = L \neq 0$. It follows that we can take the limit of both sides of the recurrence relation to get
$$
\lim_{n \to \infty} a_n = \lim_{n \to \infty} \left(1 + \frac 1{a_n} \right)\\
L = 1 + \frac 1L.
$$
As discussed above, we see that $L$ must be a fixed point of the function $f(x) = 1 + 1/x$. Continuing, we have
$$
L^2 - L - 1 = 0\\
L = \frac{1 \pm \sqrt{5}}{2}.
$$
So, there are two candidates for the limit. However, we can rule out the possibility that $L = \frac{1 - \sqrt{5}}{2} < 0$ because this sequence satisfies $a_n > 0 \implies a_{n+1} > 0$. So, the fact that $a_0 = 1 > 0$ implies that the entire sequence is positive and therefore cannot have a negative limit.

Comment: Nice thorough answer! I wonder if there are any qualitatively different (geometric?) approaches.

Answer (score 2):

We can define $a_n=\frac{b_{n+1}}{b_{n}}$ for some unknown sequence $b_{n}$ such that $b_0=1=b_1$

The equation becomes
$$
\frac{b_{n+2}}{b_{n+1}}=1+\frac{b_{n}}{b_{n+1}}
$$
or
$$
b_{n+2}-b_{n+1}+b_n=0
$$
This is the recurrence relation of the [Fibonacci numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fibonacci_sequence#Relation_to_the_golden_ratio) and so we have
$$
b_n=\frac{\varphi^{n}-\psi^{n}}{\varphi-\psi}
$$
where $\varphi$ is the golden ration and $\psi$ its coniugate.

So the original sequence is given by
$$
\lim_{n \to \infty} a_n=\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{F_{n+1}}{F_n}=\varphi:=\frac{1 +\sqrt{5}}{2}
$$
(see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fibonacci_sequence#Limit_of_consecutive_quotients))

Answer (score 0):

$a_{n+1}-a_n=\frac{1}{a_n}-\frac{1}{a_{n-1}}=\frac{a_{n-1}-a_n}{a_na_{n-1}}$ for all $n\in \mathbb{N}$.

$a_{n+2}-a_n=1+\frac{1}{a_{n+1}}-a_n=\frac{a_{n+1}+1-a_na_{n+1}}{a_{n+1}}=\frac{a_{n+1}+1-a_n-1}{a_{n+1}}=\frac{a_{n+1}-a_n}{a_{n+1}}$ for all $n\in\mathbb{N}$.

$a_0<a_1,a_2<a_1,a_2<a_3,a_4<a_3,a_4<a_5,a_6<a_5\dots$ and $a_0<a_2,a_3<a_1,a_2<a_4,a_5<a_3,a_4<a_6\dots\Rightarrow1=a_0<a_2<a_4<a_6<\dots<a_5<a_3<a_1$.

So $\{a_{2n-1}\},\{a_{2n}\}$ are convergent. If $a_{2n-1}\rightarrow l\;(\geq1)$ and $a_{2n}\rightarrow m\;(\geq1)$, then $l=1+\frac{1}{m}$ and $m=1+\frac{1}{1}$. Using these we find that $l=m$ and $l=1+\frac{1}{l}\Rightarrow l^2-l-1=0\Rightarrow l=\frac{1+\sqrt{5}}{2}$.

Answer (score 0):

$a_n=1+\frac{1}{a_{n-1}}$

Let:

$1\le a_{n-1}<2$

$\frac{1}{2}< \frac{1}{a_{n-1}}\le 1$

$\frac{3}{2}<1+\frac{1}{a_{n-1}}=a_n \le 2$

So once $a_k$ is between 1 and 2 for some $k$, it remains within those bounds for all higher $k$.

$-2 < -a_{n-1} \le -1$

$\frac{-1}{2}< a_{n}-a_{n-1}\le 1$

Equality on the right is only achieved for $a_1$ otherwise, the inequality is strict. This means that $a_n$ and $a_{n-1}$ get closer and closer together.

---

$a_n=1+\frac{1}{a_{n-1}}<a_{n-1}$

$\phi = \frac{1+\sqrt{5}}{2}$

$\psi = \frac{1-\sqrt{5}}{2}$

$a_{n-1}+1<a_{n-1}^2$

$0<(a_{n-1}-\phi)(a_{n-1}-\psi)$

$(a_{n-1}-\psi)$ is always positive.

So $a_k$ increases if $a_k<\phi$ and decreases if $a_k >\phi$

Suppose $0<\epsilon <1, $|a_k-\phi|<\epsilon$

$-\epsilon < a_k - \phi < \epsilon$

$\phi -\epsilon < a_k < \phi + \epsilon$

$\frac{1}{\phi + \epsilon}<\frac{1}{a_k}<\frac{1}{\phi - \epsilon}$

$1+\frac{1}{\phi + \epsilon}<1+\frac{1}{a_k}<1+\frac{1}{\phi - \epsilon}$

$\frac{\phi+\epsilon +1}{\phi + \epsilon}<a_{k+1}< \frac{\phi - \epsilon +1}{\phi - \epsilon}$

$\frac{\phi+\epsilon +1-\phi^2-\phi\epsilon}{\phi + \epsilon}<a_{k+1}-\phi< \frac{\phi - \epsilon +1-\phi^2+\phi \epsilon}{\phi - \epsilon}$

Since $1+\phi=\phi^2$, we can simplify:

$\frac{\epsilon(1-\phi)}{\phi+\epsilon}<a_{k+1}-\phi< \frac{\epsilon(\phi -1)}{\phi-\epsilon}$

$|\frac{\phi-1}{\phi+\epsilon}|<|\frac{\phi-1}{\phi-\epsilon}|$

$\implies \frac{-(\phi-1)\epsilon}{\phi-\epsilon}<a_{k+1}-\phi< \frac{(\phi -1)\epsilon}{\phi-\epsilon}$

$|\frac{\phi -1}{\phi - \epsilon}|<1$

So no matter how close $a_k$ is to $\phi$, it follows $a_{k+1}$ is still closer.

By comparison with a geometric series we establish convergence.